# How to use IEnumerable in C# Scripts

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

Forgive me is this is a noob question. I am new to C# and am confused by the use of IEnumerables. I am trying to iterate through a list of objects but the normal foreach method to which I am familiar doesn't work for perhaps obvious reasons. Can somebody give me an example of implementing code which iterates through a list of objects using an IEnumerable?

EDIT

```
class MyObjects : IEnumerable<LIST>
    {
        List<LIST> myTeam = new List<GroupMember>();

        public LIST this[int index]
        {
            get { return myTeam[index]; }
        }

        public IEnumerator<LIST> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return myTeam.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        IEnumerator<GroupMember> IEnumerable<GroupMember>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The above code is what I have implemented so far. I tried iterating through a returned list using foreach but it didn't work and further research revealed that I have to explicitly define the list as enumerable etc. I am just lost as to how that is achieved. And yes, nothing is obvious when you don't know what you are doing.

So, to summarise, I can call a function which returns a list of objects. I want to be able to iterate through that list of objects so that I can access values within it.

Comment: Show your code that doesn´t work as you expect.

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/ienumerable

Comment: Since IEnumerable is containing in System.Collection, just add a using directive

Comment: "doesn't work for perhaps obvious reasons". Nothing is obvious if we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Your sample code even produces more questions. Where is your type "LIST" declared and why would you implement IEnumerable in your class? Are you beware of the exception that would be thrown if your type gets iterated in a foreach loop? What is your goal to achieve with your code? Look at the link I posted above to have a resource how to properly implement IEnumerable<>

Answer (score -3):

Iterate through a range of numbers 1 to 10...

```
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
    {
        //Do something with i
    }
```

Comment: `.ToList` is entirely redundant here.